# Implement an Equatable Void (None) type

Tags: swift, generics

I am implementing result objects using [Result](https://github.com/antitypical/Result), it defines a boxed result like an Optional with an `enum`:

```
public enum Result<T, Error>: Printable, DebugPrintable {
   case Success(Box<T>)
   case Failure(Box<Error>)
   ...
}
```

The `Equatable` protocol defined for `Result` is as follows:

```
public func == <T: Equatable, Error: Equatable> (left: Result<T, Error>, right: Result<T, Error>) -> Bool
```

So, `T` must conform `Equatable`.

I would like to be able to have a `Success` that boxes a `Void` alike type. But, `Void` is not `Equatable` as it's defined as an empty tuple:

```
typealias Void = ()
```

The purpose is to be able to have `Result` types where I do not care about the a value when succeeds.

Is it possible to have an `Equatable` `Void` (or no value)?

As quick thoughts, there's the possibility to create an empty `struct`, but I am looking (if possible) for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying again in Swift 2.0, it seems that Void can be initialized as `Void()`:

```
public enum Result<T, Error: ErrorType> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(Error)

    var value: T? {
        switch self {
        case .Success(let v):
            return v
        case .Failure(_):
            return nil
        }
    }

    /// Constructs a success wrapping a `value`.
    public init(value: T) {
        self = .Success(value)
    }

    /// Constructs a failure wrapping an `error`.
    public init(error: Error) {
        self = .Failure(error)
    }
}

enum MyError: ErrorType {
    case AnError
}

let result = Result<Void, MyError>(value: Void())

let success = result.value != nil  // returns true
let error = result.value == nil    // returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not make Success contain an Optional? (`Box<T?>` or `Box<t>?`)?

The you could return nil. The downside is you would be left unwrapping your result

Comment: AFAIK, as conceived by Result, a Success *should* contain a value, otherwise it would be considered as an error. So, my question goes more in the direction of having an "Equatable none value non-optional type", for building up the enum when the value is irrelevant.

Comment: So the answer is no. If you want success to return a boxed equatable, a void doesn't meet the requirement. As you say, an empty tuple does not conform to equatable.

Comment: This is a pretty nice suggestion. But if you're deserializing a lot of times you want to know in the success branch whether there was a failure to decode and distinguish this from no value returned. For example a 200 that returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this issue is as you suggest to make a new struct that contains no members. I'll post it here for others who need a working solution.

Make it Decodable and Equatable. Now you can treat "Void" like a real type. You can just map to this value wherever you need it or map back out.

```
typealias VoidDecodableResult = ((Result<VoidDecodable, Error>) -> Void)
    
struct VoidDecodable: Decodable, Equatable {}
```

One thing is in your success block in a generic function you can just try to cast to VoidDecodable and return an instance.

```
if T.self is VoidDecodable.Type {
                    completion(.success(VoidDecodable() as! T))
                    return
                }
```

Add a helper to make mapping out easier:

```
    struct VoidDecodable: Decodable, Equatable {
    var orVoid: Void {
        ()
    }
}
```