# Equatable alternatives for Void in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to add conditional `Equatable` conformance to a type say `Box<T>`, if `T` is `Equatable`. Since `Swift.Void` is not `Equatable`, `Box<Void>` is not `Equatable`.

```
struct Box<T> {
    //...
}

extension Box: Equatable where T: Equatable {

}
```

I can define a new type like below as a solution:

```
public struct Empty: Equatable {

}
```

And then use `Box<Empty>` instead of `Box<Void>` and that would work. But, wondering if there any alternatives to introducing a new type.

**Update:**
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
struct Box<T> {
    //...
}

extension Box: Equatable where T: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Box<T>, rhs: Box<T>) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
extension Box where T == Void {
    static func ==(lhs: Box<T>, rhs: Box<T>) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I get an error during compilation: `FooBarBaz does not conform to protocol Equatable`

```
enum FooBarBaz: Equatable { 
    case success(box: Box<Void>)
    // case success(box: Box<Int>) compiles as expected.
}
```

Please note that I'm using **Swift 4.1**

Comment: Add another extension `where T == Void`?

Comment: Related: [Implement an Equatable Void (None) type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30875889/implement-an-equatable-void-none-type)

Comment: @dan I updated my question with more details. The extension does not work. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @dfri I looked at that question and I don't think they're semantically the same thing. That is, an `Optional` vs `Void`. `Void` can never have a value vs an `Optional` may have a value. Do you agree?

Comment: @pshah I agree that it's not a duplicate, hence I only mentioned it as related (and not as a proposed dupe target).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I get an error during compilation: `FooBarBaz` does not conform to protocol `Equatable`*

This half-answer focuses on explaining why the approach you've tried yourself will not (yet) work.

There is a limitation, currently, with conditional conformances, that will limit you from using this particular technique to achieve your goal. Citing [SE-0143: Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md), implemented in Swift 4.1:

> #### Multiple conformances
>
> Swift already bans programs that attempt to make the same type conform
>   to the same protocol twice, e.g.:
>
> ...
>
> This existing ban on multiple conformances is extended to conditional
>   conformances, including attempts to conform to the same protocol in
>   two different ways.
>
> ...
>
> The section [overlapping conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md#overlapping-conformances) describes some of the
>   complexities introduced by multiple conformances, to justify their
>   exclusion from this proposal. A follow-on proposal could introduce
>   support for multiple conformances, but should likely also cover
>   related features such as private conformances that are orthogonal to
>   conditional conformances.

Which wont allow us to construct multiple conditional conformances as e.g.:

```
struct Box<T> { }

extension Box: Equatable where T == Void {
    static func ==(lhs: Box<T>, rhs: Box<T>) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

// error: redundant conformance of 'Box<T>' to protocol 'Equatable'
extension Box: Equatable where T: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Box<T>, rhs: Box<T>) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if we look at your own example:

```
struct Box<T> { }

extension Box: Equatable where T: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Box<T>, rhs: Box<T>) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

extension Box where T == Void {
    static func ==(lhs: Box<T>, rhs: Box<T>) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

// error: type 'Void' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
func foo<T: Equatable>(_ _: T) { print(T.self, "is Equatable") }
foo(Box<Void>())
```

Swift accurately identifies that `Box<Void>` is not `Equatable`: the extension `Box where T == Void` will not mean that `Box<Void>` conforms to `Equatable`, as it does not leverage a conditional conformance of `Box` to `Equatable` when `T` is `Void` (it just provides a `==` method in case `T` is `Void`.

> Conditional conformances express the notion that a generic type will
>   conform to a particular protocol only when its type arguments meet
>   certain requirements.

---

As a side note, the following example yields expected results:

```
struct Box<T> { }

extension Box: Equatable where T == () {
    static func ==(lhs: Box<T>, rhs: Box<T>) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

func foo<T: Equatable>(_ _: T) { print(T.self, "is Equatable") }
foo(Box<Void>()) // Box<()> is Equatable
```

whereas, peculiarly, replacing the conditional conformance of `Box` to `Equatable` if `T == ()` with the `typedef` of `()`, namely `Void`, crashes the compiler:

```
struct Box<T> { }

extension Box: Equatable where T == Void {
    static func ==(lhs: Box<T>, rhs: Box<T>) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

func foo<T: Equatable>(_ _: T) { print(T.self, "is Equatable") }
foo(Box<Void>()) // compiler crash
```

> Assertion failed: (isActuallyCanonicalOrNull() && "Forming a CanType
>   out of a non-canonical type!"), function CanType,
>
> file /Users/buildnode/jenkins/workspace/oss-swift-4.1-package-osx/swift/include/swift/AST/Type.h,
>   line 393.
>
> ...

Edit: apparently is a (now resolved) bug:

- [SR-7101: Compiler crash when implementing a protocol for an enum using generics](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7101)

Comment: I really appreciate your help! `extension Box: Equatable where T == Void {` did the trick

Comment: So it looks like having both extensions working on `Box` simultaneously is not possible. Unfortunately, this means that a new type is required.